# What is the difference between a dirty read and a non-repeatable read?

Tags: sql, transactions, rdbms

While reading transaction isolation levels from wikipedia, I got confused by the isolation phenomena "dirty reads" and "non-repeatable reads." Both mean that if t1 selects some data, t2 modifies that same data, and then t1 reads the data again, t1 will see modified data. So what are the differences?

Answer (score 3):

- dirty reads: when you see **uncommited** changes
- non-repeatable reads: when you see successfully **committed** changes when performing the same query multiple times

the first one is evil one should avoid in most cases because you may see rows in inconsistent intermediate state while the second one is ok for many applications